# Printing takes forever and gives pixelated prints

Tags: drivers, printing, antialiasing, dpi

I have a Brother HL-3070CW printer, which has some serious issues. Printing takes an abnormally long time, and if the file has anything more than text in it, it becomes horribly aliased and pixelated. The printer also sometimes complains about running out of memory.
This problem has appeared on and off throughout various Ubuntu releases, and can sometimes be worked around by saving a file in Postscript through Evince, and printing the PS file in Evince.

I tried to install drivers from the Brother website, but it gives an error "dependency not satisfiable: hl3070cwlpr"

Help, I'm wasting a huge amount of paper and ink(not to mention time) reprinting pages over and over again in trial and error.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having a similar problem with a Brother HL-2040.